# Zero Crossings Rate

Tags: python, scipy, signals, signal-processing

I was reading a piece of code from [here](https://gist.github.com/multivac61/8a259df0bc975f605db7#file-freq_from_zcr-py):

```
def freq_from_ZCR(sig, fs):
    # Find all indices right before a rising-edge zero crossing
    indices = find((sig[1:] >= 0) & (sig[:-1] < 0))

    crossings = interpolate(indices, sig)

    return fs / np.mean(np.diff(crossings))
```

I want to check my understanding of this, as I doesn't really make sense right now. According to the mlab docs, `find` "returns the indices where some condition is true". I would like some explanation to how this works. As I see it now, `(sig[1:] >= 0) & (sig[:-1] < 0)` is a statement that is either true or false. Also, why is there a bitwise `&` there instead of an `and`?

Finally, if I assume that the first line returns an array of the indices right before a rising-edge zero crossing. Then we'll have something like (for example):

`indices = [1, 4, 7, 11, 15]`

It makes sense then to find the `np.mean(np.diff(indices))`. Why do we need the `interpolate` function and where is it from? From a quick search I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bitwise `and` because it operates on lists of Boolean values.

```
(sig[1:] >= 0)
```

returns a sequence of Booleans from the second element through the final: the first element is cut off, shifting the values left one position.

```
(sig[:-1] < 0)
```

returns a similar sequence, but below the x axis, and not shifted, but with the final element cut off.

This gives you a list of two sequences: (1) is the next value non-negative; (2) is the current value negative.  A bit-wise `and` of the two gives you `True` at each location where the function rose above the axis.

Does that explain it well enough?

**I FORGOT THE INTERPOLATION**:

SicPy has a lovely [interpolation support](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html); I expect that's what this code is using.  Without the `import` context (not included in the page you cited), I can't be certain, but SciPy and NumPy are the way to bet for these capabilities.  The idea is to find a "fractional index" at which the signal crosses 0.  It sort of assumes that the indices are equally-spaced x-coodinates, and interpolates the proper crossing point.

Comment: Definitely! Thanks :)

What about the interpolation?